# dispatchEvent not triggering jQuery.on() event listener

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code that triggers a custom named event:

```
elem.addEventListener('click', function (event)
{
    event.preventDefault();

    // Do some processing stuff

    var event = new Event('custom_event');
    this.dispatchEvent(event);
});
```

If I try to catch the custom event with jQuery.on() it works, but only when I'm not using the descendant selector filter.

So this works:

```
$('selector').on('custom_event', function () { // works });
```

But this doesn't:

```
$(document).on('custom_event', 'selector', function () { // doesn't work });
```

Can anyone shed some light on why that is? Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zyu4ahnq/3/) showing the problem.

Comment: Of course, if you're already using jQuery, you could use `$(this).trigger("custom_event")`, but I'm guessing you have a *reason* for the straight DOM code in the above (perhaps a non-jQuery library you want to be compatible with jQuery code using it?).

Comment: Yep, that's exactly the reason :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

By default the event does not bubble, so when you create an event you need to pass `bubbles: true` as an option to indicate that you want the event to be bubbled. You can use [CustomEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent) to do that.

You are using event delegation to register the second handler which makes use of event bubbling to work.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.button')[0].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var event = new CustomEvent('custom_event', {
    bubbles: true
  });
  this.dispatchEvent(event);
});

$(document).on('custom_event', '.button', function() {
  alert('Custom event captured [selector filter]');
});

$('.button').on('custom_event', function() {
  alert('Custom event captured');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="button">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: For some reason this is not working all the time. For instance if you have `jQuery(window).on('foobar', () => { … })` and then try to trigger with `document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('foobar', { bubbles: true }))` the callback of jQuery's event listener won't be executed.